# Meteor-Up Deployment Failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, deployment, meteor-up

Meteor-up is failing to deploy at the verifying stage. It's my first ever deployment. I am using mup and version meteor 1.4. Please, be little more descriptive than you would normally be. Error is following:

```
[XXX.XX.XX.XX] x Verifying Deployment: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------

package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js (wd=/bundle/bundle/programs/server)

=> Starting meteor app on port:80
assert.js:93
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"

    at wrapPathFunction (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)    
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)    
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)    
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)    
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)    
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)    
    at require (module.js:380:17)    
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)    
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)    
=> Redeploying previous version of the app

-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried mupx too and that doesn't even start. mupx setup command generates the following error:

```
Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------
Configuration file : mup.json
Settings file      : settings.json

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/node_modules/cjson/index.js:226
        throw err;
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'e' at 14:8
      "env": {}
       ^
File: "/Users/gitMonk/Desktop/projects/mup-ifix-deploy/mup.json"
    at SyntaxError (native)
    at Object.parseJSON (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/node_modules/cjson/node_modules/json-parse-helpfulerror/node_modules/jju/lib/parse.js:745:13)
    at Object.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/node_modules/cjson/node_modules/json-parse-helpfulerror/index.js:10:13)
    at Object.exports.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/node_modules/cjson/index.js:90:28)
    at Object.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/node_modules/cjson/index.js:223:24)
    at Object.exports.read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/lib/config.js:15:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/bin/mup:32:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/1091) with the current software versions.

Follow the directions in [this comment](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/1091#issuecomment-236470525) and the issue should be resolved for now.